# Tufte-book error with mtpro2 and fontenc

Tags: xetex, font-encodings, tufte, mtpro

I want to create a book in greek language in tufte style using `mtpro2` package and xetex.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{tufte-book}
\usepackage{mtpro2}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[no-math,cm-default]{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{xgreek}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text,Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text,Numbers=Lining,Scale=1.0]{Times New Roman}
\usepackage{mtpro2}
\begin{document}
Μαθηματικά
\end{document}
```

I get the following errors :

```
Command `\hbar' already defined. ...thSymbol{\hbar} {\mathord}{symbols}{"84}
Option clash for package fontspec. \usepackage
```

Comment: It's a problem with `tufte-book` which tries to do something really awful with the fonts and other things. Are you sure you want to load `xgreek`?

Comment: What are the really awful things tufte-book does with the fonts and other things?

Comment: I have another computer with all the nessesary packages installed and this example works fine. Thats why I do load the `xgreek` package. But i didnt try to unload it yet. Is it beacuse of any new version of tufte-book?

Comment: Will it work if I reinstall tufte class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\hbar` macro is defined by the `xunicode` package. Here's a modified preamble that should work okay:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{no-math,cm-default}{fontspec}
\documentclass[twoside,nofonts]{tufte-book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xgreek}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text,Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text,Numbers=Lining,Scale=1.0]{Times New Roman}
\let\hbar\relax
\usepackage{mtpro2}
\begin{document}
Μαθηματικά
\end{document}
```

I changed the following items in your preamble:

- Moved the options from `\usepackage[no-math,cm-default]{fontspec}` to the `\PassOptionsToPackage` line at the top. Since Tufte-LaTeX will load the `fontspec` package automatically, this will pass your options and you won't have an error for conflicting options.
- Added the `nofonts` option to the `\documentclass` line to suppress Tufte-LaTeX from setting its own fonts.
- Removed the first `\usepackage{mtpro2}` line. You don't need this twice.
- Removed the `\usepackage{xunicode}` and `\usepackage{xltxtra}` lines as Tufte-LateX loads these automatically for you.
- Added the `\let\hbar\relax` line just prior to loading the `mtpro2` package. This will “undefine” the `\hbar` macro so that the `mtpro2` package can define it itself.

Comment: Seems to work great! I think that the previous version of tufte-latex was working differently.

Comment: @mac, I'm glad it works for you! The Tufte-LaTeX code itself hasn't changed much at all over the past few years, but some of the packages it uses might have.